# No debian image can update/install packages

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian, nodes, debian-jessie

Unable to fetch updates from debain repository.
All our VM update/install are also facing the same error. Even if I do curl or browse from another network, I'm getting the same error for debian url.

Getting the below error:

> ```
> RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y     vim zip
>  ---> Running in 339cd82feb32
> Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
> Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
> Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
> Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
> Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
> Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
> Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
>   404  Not Found
> Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
> Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [822 kB]
> Fetched 10.1 MB in 18s (543 kB/s)
> W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y     vim zip' returned a non-zero code: 100
> ```

Comment: This seems to be a general problem with the debian jessie repositories right now: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3551

Comment: Please also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361762/apt-get-update-fails-with-404-in-a-previously-working-build/55362112#55362112 for a workaround

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.