# W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.140.204 80]

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, debian, apt

I'm trying to get a project running locally on Deepin. The project relies on node 6.10, I understand that it's an old version but it works.
When the Dockerfile tries to run the sudo apt-get update, it gives the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.140.204 80]
```

The weird thing is that I just deployed it yesterday on a Macbook without such an issue. Any ideas?

---

The mentioned duplicate question doesn't help me due to the fact that I'm not relying on a Docker image of Debian Jessie but instead using Node 6.10 which itself relies on  Debian Jessie therefore I can't manage the sources directly.

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get update fails with 404 in a previously working build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361762/apt-get-update-fails-with-404-in-a-previously-working-build)

Comment: I got my answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508948/200484
It's one of the answers from the question that @umläute mentioned, but I'm not getting option to click That solved my problem. Whereas I do get that option for the question that David mentioned.

Comment: that's because you are a user at [so] but not (yet) at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm a user at but I assume cross-site question duplication is maybe not available. I've added an answer to make this thread useful for others.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to @Awesome123 for the useful answer and other people who commented. Their suggestions were useful but didn't give an exact steps to get rid of problem because the trouble that I was having was due to an image of Node 6.10, which comes with Debian Jessie.
To resolve the issue I updated my Dockerfile with following:

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list

# As suggested by a user, for some people this line works instead of the first one. Use whichever works for your case
# RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list


RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Here is a reference to the existing answer on StackExchange where I discovered the snippet:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508948/200484

---

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested by @douglas-resende, I've updated the snippet to include a replacement of line 1 (commented), it works for some people

Comment: This one helped me resolving my gitlab build failure. Cheers!

Comment: It works, when I replace "jessie-backports" to "jessie" at first line. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @DouglasResende , After replacing "jessie-backports" to "jessie" it worked.

Comment: If you dont have control over the apt-get udpate call or have multiple apt-get calls this will add less clutter `RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add this in your DockerFIle:

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me on that case was to change the jessie version in my Dockerfile to:

```
FROM php:7.1.27-fpm-jessie
```

In my case it was php but should work with other docker images as well.