# Docker - Packages 404 Not Found From node:8-jessie

Tags: docker, debian, debian-jessie

We use node:8-jessie on our containerized environment then yesterday we suddenly encountered **Packages not found 404 error**.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then we made some adjustments on our Dockerfile based on the fix indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361762/apt-get-update-fails-with-404-in-a-previously-working-build). But we encountered the same failed to fetch error provided above with additional GPG error:

`W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1668891673`

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-jessie

RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Answer (score 5):

security.debian.org no longer contains jessie updates, you should look for them in archive.debian.org/debian-security.

Change the line pointing to that repo for this line:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

See https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/02/msg00004.html

Similarly, deb.debian.org should be changed for archive.debian.org

Comment: The link works. Now my Dockerfile became like this:

RUN rm  /etc/apt/sources.list 
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN apt-get update 

Thanks @Marcos!

Comment: Make sure to add `http://` in front of the archive url above btw

Answer (score 5):

```
FROM node:8-jessie

RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

in /etc/apt/sources.list

fixed it for me, while the other solution did not work anymore.