# podman build from debian:jessie - exit status 100

Tags: linux, docker, image, debian

I am trying to pull an image from dockerhub and update it. (Had no problem doing this previously)

Admittedly the image i am pulling is old (it is required for some legacy code) but last year i was able to do this just fine.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yq build-essential autoconf libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libproj-dev subversion valgrind dos2unix nano
```

Note: I have tried to pull many other versions (debian:8.x, debian:9.x) All result in the same exit status code, which seems to relate to packages not being found.

```
STEP 1/2: FROM debian:jessie
STEP 2/2: RUN apt-get update
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.162.132 80]
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.162.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.162.132 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.162.132 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error: building at STEP "RUN apt-get update": while running runtime: exit status 100
```

If these packages have been moved/removed, how can i redirect to install them?

EDIT: So after some reading i have progressed. The security suites have [moved](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/02/msg00004.html). I implemented code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75836790/docker-packages-404-not-found-from-node8-jessie) and updated my Dockerfile

my Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yq build-essential autoconf libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libproj-dev subversion valgrid dos2unix nano
```

This results in a similar message, "packages not found":

```
STEP 1/5: FROM debian:jessie
STEP 2/5: RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list
--> Using cache c9cb72b48445e5f242b3f57fa79cbd3a8f3c808c52527b993a34d8df104f4ab6
--> c9cb72b48445
STEP 3/5: RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
--> Using cache 9ea58aa4d817f3bb77ff9169fbbe6c5109afd7666f43f990cf827a09c2c2465e
--> 9ea58aa4d817
STEP 4/5: RUN apt-get update
--> Using cache 18cc0922b067baff243733868662ba3201e61aa2d2ec203235fb9503e2b5b769
--> 18cc0922b067
STEP 5/5: RUN apt-get install -yq build-essential autoconf libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libproj-dev subversion valgrid dos2unix nano
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libnetcdf-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libnetcdf-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libproj-dev
E: Unable to locate package valgrid
E: Unable to locate package dos2unix
E: Unable to locate package nano
Error: building at STEP "RUN apt-get install -yq build-essential autoconf libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libproj-dev subversion valgrid dos2unix nano": while running runtime: exit status 100
```

How can i find where they are? And how to i edit my Dockerfile to install them?